# New thermostat for electric radiant ceiling heat

Tags: electrical, heating, thermostat

I live in the Pacific NW where radiant ceiling heat is common in older homes. I a have home built in 1969 and want to upgrade the thermostat to something newer that we can program and save money. This should a be easy fix it would thing but having a hard time figuring out what thermostats would work with my system. I have a King Thermostat Model m601 Single Pole LR10499 22A-120/v240;18A-277VAC. So I think I need something that matches those numbers, the problem is there are 2 sets of them and not sure which I have, and finding ones that support both seems harder and I just keep finding ones like what I have inaccurate analog thermostats.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out and installed a new thermostat today, wish I could have figured it out at the beginning of the heating system. I figured out what the Single Pole LR10499 22A-120/v240;18A-277VAC means. I just had to think about it longer. So it means 22 amps for 120/240 Volt system or 18 amps for 277 volt system, and since I am in the america 277 does not matter. So I need something for 22 amp system. The next part was to figure out the voltage. I looked the breaker box and the heating system was on a double breaker so that means I need a 220/240 thermostat. I ordered a [King ESP230-R Electronic Line-Voltage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PB32EU) from amazon. I found the [king page](http://www.king-electric.com/thermostats/line-voltage-thermostats.html) has a lot info on there thermostats.

I hope this helps someone else and they can too start saving the plant and there wallet!

Comment: 277V is used if you were putting a heater in some sort of big industrial plant where everything runs off of 277Y/480 three phase.  You're right that it doesn't matter for what you're doing though.